# Retrieve data an object that is not being iterated on in Handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

In my website I'm trying to combine information from two objects. I've got a navigation object and a language object. I iterate over the navigation object, but the language object is fixed. From NodeJS the data is:

```
app.get(urljoin(relUriPathNews, ":type"), (req, res) => {
    res.render('some-page', {
        webpage: webpageInformation(),
        main_navigation: navigation
    })
})
```

in Handlebars I've got:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse"></div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-uppercase main-nav">
        {{!-- {{webpage.params.langs}} --}}
        {{#main_navigation.navigation}}
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href=/news/{{parent}}{{title}}?languages={{webpage.params.langs}}>{{title}}
                <span class="ion-ios7-arrow-right nav-icn"></span>
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu text-capitalize" role="menu">
                {{#sub_page_definition_pages}}
                <li><a href=/news/{{parent}}{{title}}?languages={{webpage.params.langs}}>{{title}}</a></li>
                {{/sub_page_definition_pages}}
            </ul> 
        </li>
        {{/main_navigation.navigation}}

    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, I iterate over `main_navigation_navigation`. Then I get `parent` and `title` from there. However, `webpage.params.langs` is from another object, ie one that I'm not iterating over, hence I get ''.

If, however I were to unquote `{{webpage.params.langs}}` from above `{{#main_navigation.navigation}}` I get the value. So it is there.

Question. How do I get the value of `webpage.params.langs` from inside the for loop of `navigation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not being able to access `webpage.params.lang` in loop since you are in context of element in current iteration. In order to access parent elements, you can use `@root` helper. Changing handlebars block to following should work -

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse"></div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-uppercase main-nav">
        {{!-- {{webpage.params.langs}} --}}
        {{#main_navigation.navigation}}
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href=/news/{{parent}}{{title}}?languages={{@root.webpage.params.langs}}>{{title}}
                <span class="ion-ios7-arrow-right nav-icn"></span>
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu text-capitalize" role="menu">
                {{#sub_page_definition_pages}}
                <li><a href=/news/{{parent}}{{title}}?languages={{@root.webpage.params.langs}}>{{title}}</a></li>
                {{/sub_page_definition_pages}}
            </ul> 
        </li>
        {{/main_navigation.navigation}}

    </ul>
</div>
```